# Why does changing the emitter-collector polarity change the collector-emitter capacitance?

Tags: mosfet, analog, bjt, capacitance

Due to some constraints, I had to use HDMI SDA and SCL lines for UART communication in a mainboard. The circuit works fine but, it fails on HDMI certifications where SCL and SDA line capacitance is required to be less than 50pF. It fails on SCL but not on SDA. SDA is about 24pF, while SCL is almost 200 pF.

The idea is when an HDMI source is plugged (hence HDMI 5V,) HDMI will work as expected but when an HDMI cable plugged in for UART communication, without 5V, the SDA and SCL lines on the connector will be used for UART communication.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSR9eG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The circuit works fine but, it fails on HDMI certifications where SCL and SDA line capacitance is required to be less than 50pF. It fails on SCL but not on SDA. SDA is about 24pF, while SCL is almost 200 pF. I replaced the NPN with NMOS but no luck there. This is the [NPN.](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bc846bdw1t1-d.pdf)

[image: output cap]

[image: cap graph]

It has above specs on parasitic capacitances. I'll cut to the case, it does not fail in below configuration (**Collector**: UartRX **Emitter**: SCL instead of **Collector**: SCL **Emitter**: UartRX configuration)

[image: emitter on SCL]

I want to understand why. How can changing the E-C polarity can lead to a difference on the line, more than 150 pF. Which parasitic capacitance is this? Is it Cbc? I do not think so because it has serial 4.7K, wouldn't show that much capacitance increase. Is it Cce? If so how? Isn't Cce or Cds the least of the parasitic capacitance? Can someone explain this phenomenon with theoritical background? (Same thing applies to NMOS as well by the way.)

Comment: You repeat yourself almost completely in two different paragraphs. Aside from that, you can see (I'm sure) that in the 1st circuit the apparent load looking backwards into the schematic should be, in theory assuming both signal BJTs are identical devices and all resistors are exact, the same. The symmetry is obvious. So there is something else you need to explain (I think you need to explain this ***before*** you worry about your BJT question): Why the difference, in theory? This is important because you seem to be reaching for a BJT explanation when you already have a difficulty to deal with.

Comment: Would it explain the difference if UARTTX is a low impedance output which idles high, and UARTRX is a high impedance input which looks like it floats uncontrollably?

Comment: @jonk I could not understand your point sir.

Comment: @Alper91 Accepted. I'll leave it there, then.

Comment: @Justme how so? I think it wouldn't be important.